# How do I clone a git repository located on my Mac connected to the internet?

Tags: linux, macos, git, ubuntu, ssh

I have an up-to-date git repo that I started on my MacBook. The project that I am working on is required to work on my university's Linux workstations that I can login to remotely via SSH. I've `cd`ed to the directory that I want to clone to on the workstation. I just have no idea how to get the SSH address for the repo on my MacBook when its connected to the internet. Also, how would this stay consistent considering I get a different IP every time I reconnect or go somewhere? Is what I'm doing even possible or a good idea?

Comment: No, it's not a good idea to expose a service running on your personal computer to the internet.

Comment: I figured that this was the case. I'm not used to git, and wanted the copy on my laptop to be the 'main' copy. Tossed this idea out the window. Instead, transferred directory to workstation (whose address is static, hence better) via FileZilla, got SSH address of it, deleted my PC copy, and used `git clone <repo>` to get it back so that now I can just `git push origin master` and `git pull origin` on my local machine. I think that's the de facto git setup I should have already had.

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to create an empty repository using a free github.com or bitbucket.org account. Using github for this example, you would then have a URL for the repo such as:

https://github.com/username/repo-name.git

Then, simply push the contents of your local repo up to the newly created online repo like so:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/repo-name.git
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git push -u origin master
```